# Dynamically allocating cssClass with knockout not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following table defined:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: timeslots">
    <td class="start-time" data-bind="text: time"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: displayStatus, class: cssClass, click: $parent.loadDetails"></td>
</tbody>
```

In my Javascript file, I am conditionally setting cssClass to various classes from a separate .css file as such:

```
// my viewmodel is a list of timeslot objects.  This is one instance
timeslot.cssClass = "event-invite";
```

I have `event-invite` defined in a css file as such:

```
.event-invite {
    background: #FFFF99;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

However, none of this css is actually binding to my element.  What is the correct way to bind the css class dynamically with knockout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind css you use this syntax:

```
<td data-bind="attr: {class: cssClass}"></td >
```

Here is the ko js page that describes this binding:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Although segFault's solution works, I think css binding is more straightforward:

```
<td data-bind="css: cssClass"></td >
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html